# GEE error while running reduceRegion: GEE Error: Provide 'geometry' parameter when aggregating over an unbounded image

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api, mean, reduceregion

I'm trying to calculate the mean soil moisture value for a particular polygon over a period of time by using `ee.Reducer.mean()` in `ee.reduceRegion()` The polygon is initially loaded as a feature; however, in reduceRegion, I am specifying `feature.geometry()` for the geometry parameter. When I run my code, I get the error:

> Element (Error) Collection.first: Error in
> map(ID=0000000000000000b79f): Image.reduceRegion: Provide 'geometry'
> parameter when aggregating over an unbounded image.

After receiving the error, I tried clipping `smam`, but it gave me the error:

> "The geometry for image clipping must be bounded."

I tried looking at [GEE Error: Provide 'geometry' parameter when aggregating over an unbounded image](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/328693/gee-error-provide-geometry-parameter-when-aggregating-over-an-unbounded-image) but both solutions provided for the problem unfortunately did not work for me. Currently, I suspect that the `feature.geometry()` for the polygon may be too large, but I do not see how this could happen as I have used `.filterBounds(table)` (table is a shapefile of an administrative region I imported) for my region of interest.

Would anyone have any idea what might be causing this error?

My code is:

```
var dataset = ee.FeatureCollection('JRC/GWIS/GlobFire/v2/FinalPerimeters').filter(ee.Filter.gte('IDate', 155725210000)).filterBounds(table);
var soilmoisture = ee.ImageCollection("NASA/SMAP/SPL3SMP_E/005").filterBounds(table);

var compute = function(feature) {
  var keepProperties = ['Id', 'IDate', 'FDate', 'system:index'];
  
  var final = ee.Feature(feature).copyProperties(feature, keepProperties);
  
  var start = ee.Number(feature.get('IDate')).subtract(604800000);
  var end = ee.Number(feature.get('IDate'));
  
  var geom = feature.geometry();
  
  var smam = soilmoisture.filterBounds(geom).filterDate(start, end).select('soil_moisture_am').mean();
  
  var reduced = smam.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), geometry: geom, scale: 9000, maxPixels: 1e9});
  final = final.set('soil_moisture_am', reduced.get('soil_moisture_am'));
  
  return final;
};

var final_dataset = dataset.map(compute);
print(final_dataset.first());
```

Answer (score 0):

That issue is produced due bad geometries in **dataset** Feature Collection. That was already considered [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/452362/calculating-the-area-of-geometry-in-feature-collection-in-google-earth-engine-fo/452462#452462). However, there are another issue related to **soilmoisture** Image Collection. You need to use a conditional statement to prevent complete masked images at Feature area. On the other hand, you don't need to use **.filterBounds** method because images are displayed on global scale.

Your [fixed code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/8f0eb29014706ff5a1a1e1ebdd648240) looks as follows:

```
var dataset = ee.FeatureCollection('JRC/GWIS/GlobFire/v2/FinalPerimeters')
  .filter(ee.Filter.gte('IDate', 155725210000))
  .filterBounds(table)
  .filter(ee.Filter.intersects(".geo", ee.Geometry.Point([0,0])).not());

//Map.addLayer(dataset);
Map.centerObject(dataset, 10);

var soilmoisture = ee.ImageCollection("NASA/SMAP/SPL3SMP_E/005").filterBounds(table);

var compute = function(feature) {
  var keepProperties = ['Id', 'IDate', 'FDate', 'system:index'];
  
  var final = ee.Feature(feature).copyProperties(feature, keepProperties);
  
  var start = ee.Number(ee.Feature(feature).get('IDate')).subtract(604800000);
  var end = ee.Number(ee.Feature(feature).get('IDate'));
  
  var geom = ee.Feature(feature).geometry();
  
  var smam = soilmoisture.filterDate(start, end).select('soil_moisture_am').mean();
  
  var reduced = smam.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), geometry: geom, scale: 9000, maxPixels: 1e9});

  return ee.Algorithms.If(ee.Number(smam.bandNames().size()).gt(0), 
                          final.set('soil_moisture_am', reduced.get('soil_moisture_am')), 
                          final.set('soil_moisture_am', 'not available'));

};

var final_dataset = dataset.map(compute);

print(final_dataset);

Map.addLayer(final_dataset, {}, 'final_dataset');

var final_dataset_areas = final_dataset.toList(final_dataset.size()).map(function (ele) {
  
  return ee.Feature(ele).geometry().area();
  
});

print(final_dataset_areas);

var test = ee.List(final_dataset.toList(final_dataset.size())).get(229); //95, 119

print("test", test);

Map.addLayer(ee.Feature(test), {color: 'yellow'}, 'test');
Map.addLayer(table, {color: 'red'}, 'table');
```

Considering an arbitrary geometry (table) in Asia, I got following result after running complete code at GEE code editor. It can be observed that there are 602 features in **final_dataset** intersecting table area. I placed one of the larger ones on the map canvas (yellow color) for comparison purposes.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!